# Dates not showing properly on plotly online

Tags: r, ggplot2, r-plotly, ggplotly

The dates of the following plot are not showing correctly when the plot is posted online with plotly.

```
library(plotly)
library(ggplot2)

# Create data
mydata <- data.frame(x = as.Date(Sys.Date()-1:100), y = runif(100))

# Plot with ggplot
myplot <- ggplot(mydata, aes(x=x, y=y)) +
geom_point()
myplot

# Plotting with plotly (local)
ggplotly(myplot)
```

The dates are recognized as dates and look fine when plotted locally.

[image]

However when I upload the same plot to plotly the dates are transformed to numbers:

```
# Uploading plot online (api credentials needed)

Sys.setenv("plotly_username"="username")
Sys.setenv("plotly_api_key"="api_key")
api_create(myplot, filename = "Stack Overflow Question")
```

[image: https://i.stack.imgur.com/4Kfao.png]

Link to online plotly:
https://plot.ly/~Nick334/8/

Link to github issue:
https://github.com/ropensci/plotly/issues/1420

Is this behaviour a bug or am I doing something wrong?

Comment: try adding `scale_x_date(date_labels="%B")` to your ggplot.

Comment: @iod Nope, [still the same](https://plot.ly/~Nick334/14/).
What this did for me was to show the full names of the months in the local plots but still no change in the online plot.

Comment: It's a stretch, and I'm firewalled from uploading things to plotly right now, but maybe replace the `as.Date` with as.POSIXct/POSIXlt? Sys.Date is already a date format anyway, so doesn't need as.Date

Comment: @iod I tried that also but it didn't work. I know, I put `as.Date` there so everyone knows for sure it's a date class :P

Comment: Well, unless someone comes up with a solution, I would recommend taking this to the ggplotly github as a potential bug.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Seems like this bug was fixed as can be seen [here](https://chart-studio.plotly.com/%7ENick334/16/#/plot).